# ActivityTransition: OnActivityReenter: onPreDraw never called

Tags: android, android-transitions

I ran into a very strange issue with postponing transition.

I postponed the return transition in `onActivityReenter`. But the problem here is that if I checked „Don’t keep activities“ in the settings of the phone, the app will most of the times just hang and show both activities over each other.

I found out that in that case `onActivityReenter` still gets called. But `onPreDraw` doesn’t, which should be called by the `onPreDrawListener` and resumes the postponed transition. So I postpone the transition forever.

What could have happened there?
The code can be found [here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/develop/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/activity/BookShelfActivity.java#L259).

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into the same issue. It's only in specific cases, and even then not 100% of the time.

Requesting the layout again after adding the listener works for me.

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(<snip>);
myView.requestLayout(); //Force a layout pass
```

I'm pretty sure this is indicative of a bug somewhere in Android, but I haven't been able to create a reliable test case. Somehow, it's skipping part of the layout pass, so the listener doesn't ever get called. Calling `requestLayout()` forces the full layout pass to happen.